# Polarization charges in a dielectric

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric

I am reading currently feynman's notes on dielectric material under the influence of electric field. And there is a part that is not very clear to me.
Here's the link to the lecture:

[https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_10.html#:~:text=Not%20if%C2%A0,away%20from%20it%3B](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_10.html#:%7E:text=Not%20if%C2%A0,away%20from%20it%3B)

Now the Polarisation $\vec P$ as a scalar represents the nr. of polarized atoms/particles per unit volumes, in other words the nr. of dipoles per unit volume. Obviously if $\vec P$ is homogeneous then the density of electric dipoles per unit volume is the same everywhere, which means we have a zero net charge inside the dielectric. Now the problem I have has to do when $\vec P$ is not homogeneous but varies within the dielectric. In this case we have charge density and the reason why is, as the text explains:

> Not if P is uniform. If the positive and negative charges being
> displaced relative to each other have the same average density, the
> fact that they are displaced does not produce any net charge inside
> the volume. On the other hand, if P were larger at one place and
> smaller at another, that would mean that more charge would be moved
> into some region than away from it.

Why would $\vec P$ not bein uniform or constant  lead to a charge density within the dielectric?
If $\vec P$ is not constant that means that in one place you would have more polarized atoms/ particles then in some other regions, why would that lead to a charge density, which I assume is different then Polarisation charges, and if yes how?

What it is meant with more charge will be moved in some region?? If you confine yourself in a region the positive and negative charges move, and they should be equal in value. Nothing actually moves, rather particles get polarized, there's no movement of charge.

Comment: Hard to say, but in my opinion Feynman is misleading when he writes "We emphasize that this is a perfectly real charge density". Maybe I have to come back to second year Physics, but I remember that I learnt that polarization charges are just an "equivalent" charge distribution that reproduces the cumulative effect of electric dipoles that are induced in microscopic structures by external electric field. Indeed each volume element dV in dielectric cannot change its charge, since  no carriers are present that can move to a neighbouring volume element. BUT, I might be completely wrong...

Answer (score 0):

The charge due to polarization *is* a real charge difference caused by real movement of charge. When a molecule has a dipole moment, it means that the probability of finding an electron is higher on one end of the molecule vs the other, which is a real difference in charge density. For example, water has a natural dipole moment because oxygen is more *electronegative* compared to hydrogen, meaning that the oxygen atom attracts the shared electrons more than the hydrogen atoms. Consequently, the charge density near the oxygen atom is more negative compared to the hydrogen atoms. The net overall charge of the molecule is zero, but there is physically a charge difference as a function of space.

Let's take a collection of identical polar molecules and arrange them into a uniform lattice where the dipole moments are all aligned. The slight positive charge that exists on one end of the polar molecule get cancelled out by the negative charge that exists on the other end of an adjacent polar molecule, so the net volume charge density is approximately zero. Note that there is nonzero charge density on the outer surface because there is no adjacent polar molecule to cancel the charge. Thus, we will have a surface with positive charge density on one end and a surface with negative charge density on the other end. Notice that from a macroscopic standpoint, this is completely equivalent to placing a set of positive charges on one surface and placing an equal amount of negative charges on another surface, and there is a *net* movement of charge from one surface to the other, even though no electrons actually traversed the entire length of the material.

Now let's say that instead of aligning all the dipole moments in the same direction, we arrange the polar molecules in a series of concentric circles and point the dipole moments away from the center of the circle. In other words, we have a non-uniform polarization (specifically, non-zero divergence). At the center of the circle, the charge density is negative because the more negative part of the molecules are pointing towards the center and there's no positive charge to cancel it out. On the surface of the circle, we will only see a net positive charge density. Overall, it is equivalent to moving some positive charge from the center to the outside. From a macroscopic electromagnetic standpoint, there was a *net* movement of negative charge from the edge to the center.